# Parity - Token disappear

Tags: parity, tokens, bug

love parity, great Ethereum Client and a stunning pace of progress. If the developers read this: Much thanks!

But there is one little tiny bug ... When I start parity and open the visual wallet in the browser, everything's fine. My balance are shown, my token are shown. But something like five minutes later the token disappear. I still see the accounts they are on, but not the token. Like as Parity lost contract wit

Comment: Similar bugs exist in Mist too. Might be related to some values on the client-side resetting or something when new blocks arrive. Can you provide a screenshot of the problem? Also, try to re-do the token query (I don't know how you do it but just do it again) and it should show the correct value.

Comment: Please also add details on which token you are missing, and if possible add accounts (if you are okay with sharing that information).

Comment: Hi, it are all.

Comment: I very often experience similar behavior, some or all tokens randomly disappearing even though status says synced. It is very random though, not sure it is worth a bug report.

Comment: My ERC20 tokens disappear often and reappear just as often. Started happening after updating client to `Parity//v1.7.11-stable-a5ed4cf-20171228/x86_64-windows-msvc/rustc1.22.1`

Comment: I also get this error in JavaScript console:
```balances::fetchTokensBalances TypeError: Cannot read property 'gt' of undefined
    at index.f1464c4a65.js:1
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at index.f1464c4a65.js:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at index.f1464c4a65.js:1
    at <anonymous>```

Comment: Clearing browser cache seems to resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Please, report this on Github.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with our token registry and has been fixed in latest releases. Please upgrade to Parity UI:

- https://github.com/parity-js/shell/releases